# Lambda parameter function in python

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, nltk

I am supposed to analyze shakespeare text using NLTK ( sentiment analysis) using python 3.4. But I get this error message:

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HAMIMOUNE\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data\shakespeare.py", line 8, in <module>
    [ line.split('\t') for line in open("AFINN-96.txt") ]))
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'v'**
```

here is my code:

```
from nltk.corpus import shakespeare
from collections import defaultdict
import json
hamlet = shakespeare.xml('hamlet.xml')
speeches = hamlet.findall('.//SPEECH')
prevSpeaker =  speeches[0].find('SPEAKER').text
afinn = dict(map(lambda k,v: (k,int(v)), 
                [ line.split('\t') for line in open("AFINN-96.txt") ])) 

dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: 0))
for speech in speeches:
    speaker = speech.find('SPEAKER').text
    lines = "\n".join(line.text for line in speech.findall('LINE') if line.text is not None)
    sentiment = sum(map(lambda word: afinn.get(word, 0), lines.lower().split()))
    dict[speaker][prevSpeaker] += sentiment
    prevSpeaker = speaker
print(json.dumps(dict, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) calls the function with an argument (a list of strings in this case). You need to adjust the `lambda` to take a parameter:

```
afinn = dict(map(lambda item: (item[0], int(item[1])), 
                 [ line.split('\t') for line in open("AFINN-96.txt") ]))
```

Alternative using dict-comprehension:

```
afinn = {k: int(v) for k, v in
         [line.split('\t') for line in open("AFINN-96.txt")]}
```

BTW, don't use `dict` as a variable name. Overwriting it prevent you to use a builtin function/type [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict).